# Why does my string compare think that '100%' < '70%'?

Tags: python, string

I am using the following code:

```
if str(percentage[0]) > '70%':
```

on the following input:

```
82%
92%
78%
73%
100%
50%
100%
67%
```

but I am getting the following output:

```
82%
92%
78%
73%
```

Why is python not evaluating and printing 100% eventhough it is true? Is there something missing in my logic?

Comment: Strings are sorted and compared as strings, not as numbers.

Comment: Strings are not numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings; these are sorted [*lexicographically*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), first characters first, then only when they match, the second characters are compared.

Thus, `'1'` comes before `'2'` *no matter what follows after*. `'70'` is greater than `'100'` because `'7'` is greater than `'1'`

Don't compare strings. Compare numbers:

```
if int(percentage[0].rstrip('%')) > 70:
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings are compared character after character:

```
1. 2. 3. 4.
-----------
7  0  %
1  0  0  %
```

You see, the first `7` is "larger" than `1` from the second string, because the characters `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9` are stored in this order.

I think the most logical would be to convert the strings to integers and compare them:

```
aa = ['82%', '92%', '100%', '73%']

nn = [int(a[:-1]) for a in aa]
# or 
nn = [int(a.rstrip('%')) for a in aa]

# nn is now [82, 92, 100, 73]

for n in nn:
    if n > 70:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are sorted and compared as strings, not as numbers.

```
In [1]: "100%" > "70%"
Out[1]: False

In [3]: int("100%"[:-1]) > int("70%"[:-1])
Out[3]: True
```